Shared site disappears in Pages configured for local setup
There is an XM Cloud multisite setup with few sites available in Pages. One of them is set as shared on the Tenant level. When I configure Pages to use my local instance, the shared site disappears from the list of sites. Why is that? How to configure shared presentation locally in this case?
Local Sitecore version is configured as the latest available in Docker (1-ltsc2022).

does your content on your local instance match what you have in your cloud instance?

Indeed, that was a content issue. The site item was missing under /Settings/Site Grouping in local setup. @Richard Seal, feel free to post it as an answer so that I could accept it.
